# Firebase subescribe to topic notworking in android 10

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to Subscribe a topic in firebase . also im doin this

```
 var topic = "test"
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic).addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Subscribed $topic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Log.d("TAG_" , "$it")
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Subscribe $topic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }.addOnCompleteListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "on compilete ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

for subscribing the test topic , at the end i got nothing for result !!!. the topic Subscribed in android 6 but not working in android 10.
im sure that implement the channelId for above android O

Comment: Did you implement the channelId

Comment: yeah im implement it @Ticherhaz FreePalestine